# Como colocar a lista de letras recebidas da base de dados na posição horizontal e juntá-la numa só página à lista de palavras da letra pesquisada

Tags: php, html

Estou a construir a base de dados de um dicionário e fiz os código da página indice.php que mostra as letras do abecedário:

a) A lista aparece na vertical mas eu queria na horizontal.
b) Como juntar na mesma página a lista de letras e a lista de palavras?

Podemos ver aqui nestas páginas:

```
https://www.corampopulo.pt/login/dicionario-penal/indice.php
https://www.corampopulo.pt/login/dicionario-penal/lista.php
```

...

**Segue o código da página 1...**

```
<?php

    include 'conn.php';

    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(SUBSTR(`Palavra`, 1, 1)) As abc from Definicoes_palavras";

    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
           <meta charset="utf-8">
    Indice das Letras
    <br/><br/>
    <?php 
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                ?>
                <a href='lista.php?letter=<?php echo base64_encode($row["abc"]); ?>'><? echo strtoupper($row["abc"]); ?></a><br/>
                <?
            }
        }
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php

    $conn->close();

    ?>
```

**Segue o código da página 2...**

```
    <?php 
include 'conn.php';

$letter = mysqli_real_escape_string ($conn,htmlspecialchars(base64_decode($_GET["letter"])));

$sql = "SELECT Id,Palavra from Definicoes_palavras where Pronta != 0 AND Palavra LIKE '".$letter."%'";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
<h2>Letra <?php echo $letter;?> </h2>
<br/><br/>
 <a href="https://www.corampopulo.pt/login/dicionario-penal/indice.php">Voltar ao Índice</a>
                   <br> <br>

<h4>Seleccione um item da lista:</h4>

<?php 
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            ?>

             <a href='fundamentacao1.php?word=<?php echo base64_encode($row["Id"]); ?>'><? echo $row["Palavra"]; ?></a><br/>
            <?
        }
    }
?>
</body>
</html>

<?php

$conn->close();

?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para ele ficar lado a lado é só vc retirar o `<br>` dessa linha:

```
<a href='lista.php?letter=<?php echo base64_encode($row["abc"]); ?>'><? echo strtoupper($row["abc"]); ?></a><br/>
```

Ficando dessa forma:

```
<a href='lista.php?letter=<?php echo base64_encode($row["abc"]); ?>'><? echo strtoupper($row["abc"]); ?></a>
```

Se precisar espaçar a letras só adicionar:

```
echo "&nbsp;";
```

no final da tag  que o &nbsp é um código HTML para espaçamento

Comment: Ok é isso mesmo Luan Brito... outra pessoa amiga já me tinha explicado quase ao mesmo tempo do seu post. Mas muito obrigado na mesma.

Comment: opa tranquilo então fera